# Qt 5 migration - Cannot open include file: 'ui_mainwindow.h'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to migrate a simple project to Qt 5. The project was originally written for Qt 4, and it compiles fine there.

When compiling with Qt 5, however, I'm getting this error:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_mainwindow.h': No such file or directory
```

Now I know that ui_mainwindow.h should be auto-generated when compiling, and I've checked and it is not being generated when compiling with Qt 5.

---

**Note**

This happens on a newly created project as well.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new project under Qt Creator + Qt 4.
2. Copy project to another machine where Qt Creator + Qt 5 has been installed.
3. Open project, after fixing some initial errors this one pops up.

Comment: Make sure you're adding the widgets module. Something like this in your .pro: `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets`

Comment: I had to add `QT += widgets` even to reach that error, I was dealing with other errors before that :)

Comment: Check out the Makefile generated by qmake. You should see a section similar to this: `compiler_uic_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) ui_mainwindow.h
ui_mainwindow.h: ../widgettest/mainwindow.ui
    /Users/kevin/Development/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/uic ../widgettest/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h`

Does the uic executable that it references actually exist?

Comment: Clear your project and build it. Do you see `uic` being called? Could you post your `.pro` file?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal I'm building the project on Windows, however, and I can't call 'make distclean', even when I start from the special prompt for Qt 5. I'm building it using Qt Creator. Btw "Rebuild" from Qt Creator's own menus doesn't work, if that's what you meant.

Comment: One possible issue is that `Clean All` or `Rebuild All` does not delete your Makefile. Try deleting it manualy (or better: delete the entire build folder)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Ok, this is weird, it worked after I deleted the debug and release folders **now**. But since I hadn't copied them on the other machine (the one with Qt 5) to begin with, this is very, very weird why it helped now. Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me in the end was deleting both the Debug and Release build folders. What is strange is that I hadn't copied them initially, so I have no idea why it helped deleting them after they were first created.

But if anyone has this problem, try deleting the Debug and Release folders, as well as the .user file. This should force Qt Creator to reconfigure your project.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I used cmake instead of qmake to build my project,
and I solved it in cmake by adding:

```
FILE(GLOB UIs *.ui)
# to generate header files for .ui files
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS  ${UIs})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; solved cleaning the project (From Qt->Build) and adding:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

As an example, this is my CMakeLists.txt working well:

```
#Specify the minimum version of CMake (3.1 is currently recommended by Qt)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

# Specify project title
project(challenge_MarcoRuiz)

# To automatically run MOC when building (Meta Object Compiler)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# To automatically run UIC when building (User Interface Compiler)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# To automatically run RCC when building (Resource Compiler)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

# Specify OpenCV folder, and take care of dependencies and includes
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Take care of Qt dependencies
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets REQUIRED)

## 
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# add required source, header, ui and resource files
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "mainwindow.h" "mainwindow.cpp" "mainwindow.ui" ${UI_HEADERS})

# link required libs
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${UI_HEADERS})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is very strange and patience testing error,it happened to me as well a few days ago when my working code start showing this error,am not sure but for me it was due to the fact that my mainwindow.ui and mainwindow.qrc was not compiled so I take the following steps

1. compiled the mainwindow.ui (right click on mainwindow.ui file in the solution Explorer and select compile )and it gave something C:\Qt1\5.9\msvc2017_64\lib\rcc.exe which was missing in that destination,so I went to C:\Qt1\5.9\msvc2015_64\bin,copy and paste rcc.exe from C:\Qt1\5.9\msvc2015_64\bin to C:\Qt1\5.9\msvc2017_64\lib
2. compile these two file once again and built the code again
3. no error that is it .