# error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_MainWindow.h': No such file or directory, Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm trying to get a project that I downloaded from Github (https://github.com/Y-Vladimir/SmartDeblur) working in Qt Creator 3.4.1. However, when I build the project I get the two errors below.

[image]

I literally just installed Qt today, but from what I can gather those two ui files should be automatically generated when I compile. I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using an old version of Qt (4.8, the same  version the Github project uses). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711564/qt-5-migration-cannot-open-include-file-ui-mainwindow-h) that seems related, but I couldn't get it working.

Can someone help me figure this issue out? Thanks